# Why there is a 'amd' property in 'define' function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, amd

I am learning jQuery and Backbone source code, and noticed they check if there is requirejs:

[jQuery 1.9.1](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js)

```
if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd && define.amd.jQuery ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function () { return jQuery; } );
}
```

[Backbone](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js)

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
```

Why there always have a `amd` property in `define` function in requirejs?

And the `define.amd` always is an object which key `jQuery` is `true`? Even I have not import the jQuery module?

Comment: http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a convention that AMD loaders should use to indicate that the `define` they export into the global space is the `define` that is made to be used by AMD modules to define themselves.

If AMD loaders did not use this convention then if some random JavaScript library decided to export a `define` function into the global space that has nothing to do with AMD, then code which is designed to work with or without an AMD loader would erroneously believe that they are used in an environment where an AMD loader is present.

There is still a risk for things to go askew if some random third party library decided to also export its own `define` function (that has nothing to do with defining AMD modules) *and* decided to add an `amd` property to it, but the risk is much lower than if the scheme I explained above was not used.

So jQuery and Backbone in the code you've shown tests whether it is used in an AMD environment where an AMD loader is present, and if so defines itself as an AMD module.

`define.amd.jQuery` is specific to jQuery and indicates that the loader is able to account for multiple version of jQuery being loaded simultaneously.